# How to acces exiv2 ImageSize Property?

Tags: bash, exif, exiv2

I create images from blender, and they lack Exif metadata, which I add using the bash command `exiv2`. (Because the software these images are passed to will use the metadata.)

For example, I can set the Image Width to 960 using `exiv2 -M"set Exif.Image.ImageWidth 960" image.jpg` and then read it out using `exiv2 -g Exif.Image.ImageWidth -Pv image.jpg`.

For a quick summary, I can do `exiv2 image.jpg` to get a list of set Exif metadata. This includes

```
$ exiv2 image.jpg
File name       : image.jpg
File size       : 32975 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 960 x 540
```

How can I use this `Image size` to set `Exif.Image.ImageWidth` and `Exif.Image.ImageLength` in bash?

The [standard Exif tags](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) don't list `ImageSize`.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far that you're having trouble with?  Like, ooh, perhaps `read`ing output from process substitution, or using `$BASH_REMATCH`? Tell us what trouble you're having with the approach you've selected, and we'll be happy to help you through the rough spots.

Comment: @ghoti I was hoping for a way to get the numbers for width and height from exiv2 without having to parse a string. It seems to be something that is probably available but I just don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ghoti suggested, parsing the output works:

```
exiv2 image.jpg  | grep  "Image size" | sed -n "s/^.*Image size\s*:\s\([0-9]*\)\sx\s\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/p"
```

gives the width, and

```
exiv2 lowerCircle_0100.jpg  | grep  "Image size" | sed -n "s/^.*Image size\s*:\s\([0-9]*\)\sx\s\([0-9]*\).*$/\2/p"
```

the height.

I'm still hoping for a cleaner answer though.

Explanation of the sed command:

```
 sed -n "s/^.*Image size\s*:\s\([0-9].*\)\sx\s\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/p"

 -n            suppress printing
 "s/           substitute match
 ^.*           everything from the start
 Image size    until "Image size" is encountered
 \s*:\s        whitespace, colon, a single space
 ([0-9]*\)    any number of digits. store that in \1
 \sx\s         space x space
 ([0-9]*\)    another group of digits. store that in \2
 .*$           everything until the end of line
 /\1           substitute all that with the first group
 /p"           and print the substituted result
```

Comment: If this is what you've tried, then it seems like adding it to your question would make the most sense, along with a clear statement as to WHY this doesn't meet your needs. It works as an answer as well, I suppose, but you're likely to get more answers and fewer downvotes if your question shows your efforts so far.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments ghoti. This is not what I tried, or even what I wanted, because it seemed like there should be an inbuilt easier way. But since my question didn't get much attention apart from downvotes, I tried your suggestion of parsing the text output myself. I'll leave it as an answer, because it actually is one (even though I consider it a non-beautiful answer). I personally don't care about attracting more answers now, since this was not ideal to set up, but works now.

Comment: Hrm. Clarity on how you expect to extract text from the output of that command without parsing strings would be good. It almost seems you're asking for usage help with exiv2 rather than help with a programming task. I'd be happy to contribute an answer to a better quality question. But if you're not interested in taking this further, you might want to consider just deleting the question to avoid further downvotes.

Comment: I was expecting there to be some functionality provided by `exiv2` to get only the value of the `ImageSize` field, just like there is the command to get just the value of the `Exif.Image.ImageWidth` and that I was just unable to find documentation on it. Is the only issue you have with my question that it does not mention what I tried?

Comment: I just took a look at the options for `exiv2`. Looks like the "command file" used by the `-M` option is documented to include only `set`, `add` and `del` commands, and the `pr`int action contains no options to restrict what's being shown. Seems pretty clear to me that you either need to parse the output of `exiv2`, or you need to use a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

or without sed hieroglyphs

```
exiv2 pr  X.jpg | awk -F: '/Image size/ {print $2}' | cut -dx -f1 | tr -d ' '
```

and

```
exiv2 pr  X.jpg | awk -F: '/Image size/ {print $2}' | cut -dx -f2 | tr -d ' '
```